# do while loop not functioning and my code running infinite loop when i refresh

Tags: javascript, html

the switch case is working except case case "fas fa-random" on musicAudio addEventListener ended, whenever the music ended, it will not select random song. if i refresh the page it will go into infinite loop

html

```
<audio id="main-audio" src=""></audio>
```

javascript

```
let musicIndex = 1;
repeatBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
const getClass = repeatBtn.className;
switch(getClass){
    case "fas fa-redo":
        repeatBtn.className = "fas fa-random";
        repeatBtn.setAttribute("title", "Playlist Shuffle")
    break;
        break;
    case "fas fa-random":
        repeatBtn.className = "fas fa-stop-circle";
        repeatBtn.setAttribute("title", "Song Repeat")
    break;
    case "fas fa-stop-circle":
    repeatBtn.className = "fas fa-redo";
    repeatBtn.setAttribute("title", "Song Looped")
    break;
}
})

musicAudio.addEventListener('ended', () => {

const getClass = repeatBtn.className;
switch(getClass){
    case "fas fa-random":
        let randIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * allMusic.length) + 1;
        do{
            Math.floor(Math.random() * allMusic.length) + 1;
        }while(musicIndex = randIndex);
        const test = musicIndex = randIndex;
        loadMusic(musicIndex);
        playMusic();
        break;
    case "fas fa-stop-circle":
        musicAudio.currentTime = 0;
        loadMusic(indexNumb)
        break;
    case "fas fa-redo":
        nextMusic()
        break;
}
})
```

Comment: `while(musicIndex = randIndex);` you're missing a `=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition is currently an assignment, rather than a comparison.

You wrote:

```js
// ...
while(musicIndex = randIndex);
// ...
```

Which should be:

```js
// ...
while(musicIndex == randIndex);
// ...
```

See [Difference Between =, ==, and === in JavaScript](https://www.guru99.com/difference-equality-strict-operator-javascript.html)